# How to open up each CSV file in current directory and add column of data based on CSV file name with an automated script

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have a group of CSV files all with a specific name that includes a date (e.g., `Reserve013112-sheet1.csv`, `Reserve013112-sheet2.csv`).

All of the files have a date in the file name following the "Reserve" word. I want to extract that date (in date format) and add a column to the existing CSV (potentially insert it as the first column in the `.csv` file) as follows:

old file:

```
number,status,reserve,open,code
110035,OPEN,250000,yes,no,12
110056,AUTO,30000,no,yes,0
...
```

new file:

```
date,number,status,reserve,open,code
01-31-2012,110035,OPEN,250000,yes,no,12
01-31-2012,110056,AUTO,30000,no,yes,0
...
```

I want to do this automatically (potentially with a batch file).

I have a script that already converts my existing excel files to `csv` files, which I want to run in a batch file right before the script that adds the date to each of the files.

Comment: Have you tried anything and run into a specific issue? Be sure that your question doesn't boil down to more than 'write code with these specifications' in order to incentivize people to help you out.

Comment: I have tried the following:
1. Create an empty excel file with a macro where the macro opens up each of the csv files in the current directory (which the macro that I found is not working).
2. Then automatically start the macro from a batch file located in the same directory.
I am not sure if this is the right approach or not.

Comment: I tried using the following macro:
http://www.zerrtech.com/content/excel-vba-open-all-files-a-directory

I edited the macro to pull the correct text from the file name, but I think where the macro is catching right now is on the ".NewSearch" line. I believe this line is giving me the error: Object doesn't support this action.

Comment: In general I was not sure if this approach was the "best" approach, which is why I initially just offered up the question for a more efficient way of automatically adding a column of data to a csv file.

Comment: 'Best' usually falls into the category of 'opinion', which S.O. tries to avoid. I'd encourage you to post the batch code you're using and having difficulty with. Check http://www.sscce.org for a good primer on how to ask a detailed, answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

As with many text processing tasks, the job can be made simple and efficient with a good regular expression utility. An excellent option is [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), a pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) utility that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The solution below first uses FOR to list the `*reserve*.csv` files.

Next it uses FOR /F coupled with JREPL.BAT to parse out the month, day, and year from the file name. If the values are not found, then the file is skipped.

Finally it uses another JREPL.BAT call to insert either "date," at the beginning of the first line, or "mm-dd-20yy," at the beginning of all other lines. This last command uses the output `/O -` option to overwrite the original file with the result.

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /vin "^date," *reserve*.csv'
) do for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (
  'echo %%F^|jrepl "^.*Reserve(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).*" "$1 $2 $3"'
) do call jrepl "^" "(ln==1)?'date,':'%%A-%%B-20%%C,'" /j /f "%%F" /o -
```

There is one potential problem with the above - it will modify a file, even if it already has the date at the beginning of each line. A bit more user supplied JSCRIPT can be used to prevent modification of files that already have the date as the first column.

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'findstr /vin "^date," *reserve*.csv'
) do for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (
  'echo %%F^|jrepl "^.*Reserve(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d).*" "$1 $2 $3"'
) do call jrepl "^" "(ln==1)?'date,':'%%A-%%B-20%%C,'" /j /f "%%F" /o - ^
                /jbegln "if (ln==1 && $txt.search(/^date,/i)>=0) skip=true"
```